# After making a list of items in a string how do I have the selected item open a image pop up

Tags: java

I want to try to ask my crush out using a program where he selects a type of meme and a pop up with the meme that asks him out shows up after he selects that option, but I don't remember how to do that. I'm pretty sure array lists need to be used?? I'm not really sure. Could someone please help? Thanks

```java
public class extra {
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("image1.jpg");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list_of_items = {"Kermit the Frog", "BTS", "Tumblr Screenshot",
                "Anxiety", "Vines", "Gravity Falls"};
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image0.jpg");
        input = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What is your prefered type of meme?",
                Buzzfeedesque Quiz, 1, 1, icon, list_of_items, list_of_items[0]);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the program:

```
public class Main {

    static String[] memes = {"Kermit the Frog", "BTS", "Tumblr Screenshot", "Anxiety", "Vines", "Gravity Falls"};
    static String[] paths = {"", "", "", "", "", ""};
    static String[] messages = {"message_1", "message_2", "message_3", "message_4", "message_5", "message_6"};
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[memes.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < memes.length; i++) {

            buttonArray[i] = new JButton();
            buttonArray[i].setText(memes[i]);
            gbc.gridx = i;
            final int index = i;
            buttonArray[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messages[index], memes[index], JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(paths[index]));

                }

            });
            jf.add(buttonArray[i], gbc);

        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you get the paths of the images correct and import all of the packages